# Install an appx manually on multiple Windows Phone 8.1 devices

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, appx

I'm doing a Windows Phone 8.1 application. It works ok, I can try it on emulator and on my phone, because I've registered it.

Now, I have to pass the app to my client to test it (they are going to test it on multiple devices). I was looking but I didn't find any aswer to this questions:

- How can I create and send them an appx that they can install on their phones?
- What kind of developer license I need?
- Do they have to register their phones with the same certificate I create the appx?
- How can they install the appx I've sent them via email for example?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sideloading Windows Phone appx files is not directly possible if the device is no registered developer device. And sadly there can be only 3 devices registered.

You can set up a new app in your developer account dashboard and submit it to the store as a beta version. Then you can "invite" up to 10000 people by entering their email addresses.

More info here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj215598%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you, that's sound great. Do you know what kind of license I need (free license, individual, or company)?

Comment: Sorry, i don't know about that.