# Can't install Enterprise App developed in cordova(phonegap) on windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows, cordova, powershell, windows-phone-8, phonegap-cli

I have developed a cordova app for windows phone 8.1 by adding `windows` platform.

Cordova Version: 6.0.0, 
Windows Platform Version: 4.3.1,
Visual Studio 2015 Update 2

The app runs successfully when running in Debug Mode with `ARM` or `AnyCpu` selected on developer registered windows phone 8.1.

**Steps performed while signing the app :**

1.Add the required values(Package Name, Package Display Name, Version) on the following line in the `packageapp.phone.appmanifest`.

```
<Identity Name="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" Publisher="xxxxxxxxxx" Version="1.0.0.0" />
```

- Left below line as it is(ie. the one that was generated while project creation)

`<mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" PhonePublisherId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />`

- Kept Id same as Name in Identity.

`<Application Id="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" StartPage="www/index.html">`

- Added Display Name, Publisher Display Name, Description, default language
- Changed the following in `config.xml`. This id in the widget tag is same as Name in the Identity Tag.

`<widget id="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" version="1.0.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>App Name</name>
 </widget>`

2. Clean Solution and Build it in **Release** mode `(ARM)` and the `appx` file gets generate successfully at below location of project :

   `PathToProject\platforms\windows\build\phone\Release\ARM`
3. Installed software "Microsoft Intune Company Portal for Windows Phone"

4.Place AET.aet , AET.aetx , AET.xml file in  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Corporation\Microsoft Intune Company Portal for Windows Phone"

5. Open `PowerShell` from start menu and Run as Administration.
6. Navigate to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Corporation\Microsoft Intune Company Portal for Windows Phone" in power shell.
7. Run command

   `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy AllSigned`

8.Run following script in PowerShell:

`.\Sign-WinPhoneCompanyPortal.ps1 -InputAppx "PathToAppxFile\App.appx" -PfxFilePath "PathToPFXFile\PFXName.pfx" -PfxPassword xxxxxxxxxx -AetxPath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Corporation\Microsoft Intune Company Portal for Windows Phone\AET.aetx"`

8. Give Output Parameter name of signed .appx file you want to generate. For example MyApp.appx
9. Copy .aetx file to phone storage and tap on .aetx file. This will enroll device to access company app.
10. After installing .aetx file in device copy signed .appx file to phone storage and tap on file for installation.

I have also tried Project-->Store-->Create App Packages-->No and got successful Validation Result while creating App Package. I even tried uploading  .appxupload file to Windows Dev Center and it was successful.

**Issue :** While signing the app using enterprise certificate and installing it on the device I get the an Error. Please find attached screenshot for the same.

[image]

I have also tried the following links to no avail:

1. [Windows Phone 8.1 HTML Company Apps - Can't install company app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31837144/windows-phone-8-1-html-company-apps-cant-install-company-app), ["Can't install company app" on Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25364419/cant-install-company-app-on-windows-phone-8)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32766973/sideloading-universal-windows-phone-8-1-company-app-on-windows-phone-8-1
3. [Install an appx manually on multiple Windows Phone 8.1 devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497881/install-an-appx-manually-on-multiple-windows-phone-8-1-devices?rq=1)
4. [How to install Windows Phone 8.1 app in other phones in the simplest way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29507269/how-to-install-windows-phone-8-1-app-in-other-phones-in-the-simplest-way?rq=1).

**Note:** The project has been developed using command line and not by using default template of Visual Studio

My App has been submitted in App Store and can be downloaded and installed on the device successfully signed with same certificate. Can somebody please shed some light where I am missing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This FAQ should also help. Read the **bold** sentences first. [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

Comment: My App has been submitted in App Store now and can be downloaded and installed on the device successfully signed with same enterprise certificate. So I don't think above thread will help me.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for replying. Best of Luck with your app.

Comment: Did you try removing the WinJS 2.1 reference from the Cordova solution that is created when you build your main solution?

Comment: No. I had no idea that it might have an impact for installing an executable signed with Enterprise certificate because I never faced build errors due to WinJS Reference.

Comment: not sure if it's of any use any more i ran into the same problem, I found out my Publisher name on the signed app was different that the one in the certificate. - But this link [ https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/09/01/enterprise-distribution-of-windows-phone-applications.aspx ] helped me